# Xorg heat more CPU than Wayland in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, xorg, overheating, wayland

I'm using Gnome in Ubuntu 17.10 (I have this same behavior with default Ubuntu desktop and vanilla Gnome)

With Wayland my CPU is 45ºC

With Xorg my CPU is 51ºC

I'm using Xorg because i need to adjust xgamma in my laptop and I can't do it in Wayland (I think it is not possible in Wayland)

It is possible to cold Xorg? change renderer engine to GPU or anything? (maybe it is a silly question)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Differences should be expected and wayland is supposed to be an improvement. The thermal differences here are negligible, nothing needs to be cooled down.

Comment: 51C isn't too hot. Does it overheat on more intensive tasks?

Comment: 51C not too hot, ok, but the laptop cooler starts to run and making noise at about 54C, so with some little task that take CPU it began to run. In Wayland cooler starts very occasionally.